# What element in WIX XML sets the description field of the process shown in the Windows Task Manager?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-services, installation, wix

I have a WIX that installs a C# windows service. Everything is good. It would be even better if I  somehow is able to change the description field of the process when it's displayed in the Windows Task Manager. I thought the description in this element would do it but apparently it's not:

```
<Component Id="MyWindowsServiceExeComponent" Guid="*">
<File Id="MyWindowsServiceExe" 
      Name=".My.WindowsService.exe" 
      KeyPath="yes" 
      DiskId="1" 
      Source="$(var.SourceFileDir)My.WindowsService.exe" />
<ServiceInstall 
      Id="MyServiceInstaller" 
      Name="MyServiceInstaller"
      DisplayName="My Service" 
      Type="ownProcess" 
      Start="auto" 
      ErrorControl="normal" 
      Vital="yes"
      Account="LocalSystem"
      Description="Provides services for all components." />
```

Answer (score 1):

The .exe will use the assembly attribute [AssemblyTitle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973231.aspx) in task manager.

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("This is my description")]
```

The name and display name specified in your serviceInstall element relate to name and description as viewed in service control manager (services.msc)

Answer (score 0):

The DisplayName and Description in serviceIntaller.designer.cs are the ones that show up in services list(run services.msc to check that out) and the ServiceName is the one that shows up in Taskmanager -> Service.